# Start batch through powershell without getting asked for administration rights

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Is there a way to start a batch file with administration rights using Powershell? (I mean in a way that you won't have to click a yes start thing that pops up.)

Comment: You are asking for a security hole as a feature. (If this were possible, all malware would do it.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I thought there may be a way to pass special credentials or so. Malware won't have them.

Comment: You asked about bypassing the UAC dialog. The answer is that you cannot.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Sorry if my formulation was bad. I am not trying to bypass the dialog. I was asking if I could authenticate without showing it to the user. The thing is I am trying to remotely execute a batch (may could change the data format) on a server and if I want to do that I'd need to know a way to authenticate programmatically.

Comment: Why do you need to run the script elevated?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart because it calls some exe files which require to be started elevated.

Comment: You cannot automatically elevate from a non-elevated session without provoking the UAC prompt. If a program requires elevation, you must either authenticate at the UAC prompt or run the program from a process that is already elevated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you

- Disable UAC, or
- have PowerShell already running with administrative privileges

The entire point of UAC and selective elevation is that it's a noticeable action.

Answer (score 0):

you can set variable `__COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker` (though it will give you no admin permissions for some operations [pop-up will not appear](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317510/how-to-use-the-compatibility-administrator-utility-in-windows)) or disable UAC